# How to Update in sqlalchemy using objects?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a student table in postgres with the following columns
Studentid | Student_name | Student_division

I am using sql alchemy and have modeled it as

```
     Class Student:
     _tablename__ : 'student'
     __table_args__ : {'schema' : 'student'}

     studentid=Column('Student_name', pk=true)
.
. And so on for rest of the columns.

#After creating object of the same
    stu = Student()

#I want the values be updated by user.
#The statement i have written is as
    x= session.query(Student).get(id) #id #given by user
    x.studentid= studentid #given by uset #models
    x.studentname = name
    session.add(x)
    session.commit()
```

How to update? This doesnt work.

Comment: remove `session.add(x)`, and just do simple commit `session.commit()`.

Comment: That whole query doen't make much sense to me. Shouldn't it be something like `x = session.query(Student).get(studentid)`...

Comment: @Jeronimo  Yes you are right, I have edited it, but is there a way we can use object of class and then update?

Comment: @Megh adding answer for this problem

Comment: @Megh That's what @sahasrara62 meant, you just `commit` the session and since you modified attributes on object `x`, this will cause an sql update query being built and executed implicitly by sqlalchemy at this moment. Or am I missunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Jeronimo thanks for clarifying. I meant is some manipulation or operations possible on stu i.e the object of class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to commit the changes and remove the `session.add(x)`

just keep `session.commit()`